# Can not make Polymer ready when number of imports and file size are large

Tags: polymer

I can run all the following *simplified* code in jsbin without any error.  The size of the real code is large - it contains many imports, and properties and functions within Polymer().

The real version of the following simplified version of `index.html` has been working fine with both Iceweasel and Chromium in *localhost*:
(version 1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id="my-element">
        <template>
            <paper-input></paper-input>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function(){
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-element'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when the *real* version of above `index.html` is served from remote host, the function passed to `HTMLImports.whenReady` never gets called. Besides, Iceweal complains `ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined`.

Then I borrow [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577633/using-htmlimports-whenready-not-working-in-chrome) to have this version (version 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id="my-element">
        <template>
            <paper-input></paper-input>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        var init=function(){
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-element'
            });
        };
        if(HTMLImports.ready)
            init();
        else{
            console.log("called"); //Always comes here!
            HTMLImports.whenReady(init);
        }
    </script>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

comment for above version: The real large version always runs to `HTMLImports.whenReady(init);` but function `init()` never gets called.

I also tried [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265769/polymer-1-0-on-firefox-referenceerror-polymer-is-not-defined) and make the simplified code look like this (version 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id="my-element">
        <template>
            <paper-input></paper-input>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',function(){
            console.log("called"); //Never gets called!
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-element'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

`console.log()` in the above version is never executed.

How do I change the code so that it guarantees every element will be properly loaded even in cases where the file size is big and network and server are slow?

Thank you in advance!

*(edit 1)*
My browsers respond today differently than last night:

- version 1: Both Iceweasel (i.e. Firefox?) and Chromium (i.e. Chrome?) remain silent and yield a blank page without any error or warning in developer's console.
- version 2, version 3, and @akc42's version: Chromium displays the expected correct page. Iceweasel complains `ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined`.

*(edit 2)*
My test results are different from those 20 minutes ago as follows:

- version 2: Chromium gives blank page. Iceweasel complains `ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined`.
- version 3: Chromium complains `Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined`. Iceweasel complains `ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined'.

I am reading the `note` [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#main-document-definitions). I will split `index.html` into two and see if it make any different results.

*(edit 3)*
I am sad to report that splitting `index.html` into two files does not make any difference - both Chromium and Iceweasel quietly give blank page.

(version 4):

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="my-element.html">
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

`my-element.html` (version 4a):

```
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <dom-module id="my-element">
        <template>
            <paper-input></paper-input>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function(){
            console.log("called"); //Never gets called!
            Polymer({
                is: 'my-element'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

`my-element.html` (version 4b):

```
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <dom-module id="my-element">
        <template>
            <paper-input></paper-input>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-element'
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to look in the developer's console and see what kind of errors or warning messages you are getting. It could be any number of problems, it's impossible to guess without more information.

Comment: @ScottMiles There is no error or warning in developer's console. That is the most difficult situation for me to debug when browsers do not complain but just show me a blank page :-( Side note: The fact that I am able to open the imported files means to me that the import files do exist in file system's directory.

Comment: The Network panel in the developer's console will show you the state of all your imports and so there should be no question as to whether the files loaded correctly.

Comment: @ScottMiles Thank for the enlightenment! Yes - the status for the import files is `200`.

Comment: @ScottMiles I am sorry! I should have reported the warnings from Chromium: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://example.com/a.css".
(index):1 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://example.com/paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-common.css".
(index):1 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://example.com/b.css".`

Comment: Those warnings can all be ignored. I'm afraid we won't be able to help you unless you can provide more details or a failing example. If the simple versions work, then your setup is ok. Therefore, it's unlikely that the sheer size of your project is the problem, and more likely you have just made a mistake somewhere. Maybe you can try building your project up a little bit at a time until you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to the helps from @ScottMiles and @akc42 !

My troubles turns out to come from ClouldFlare's cloud services. Their cache system heavily rewrites nearly all of my import files.

After I bypass CloudFlare's cloud, Chromium is happy with versions 1 and 4; Iceweasel complains `ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined' but displays the correct page with version 4.

Nevertheless, I much like their services. So, I will see if I can acquire their helps. (Currently I am using their free services)

Meanwhile, I will try `vulcanize` to see if the compressed single file is immune to ClouldFlare's cache system.

If anyone is generous to share your successful experience with ClouldFlare and Polymer, I will be much grateful, too.

*(edit)*
After I bypass CloudFlare's cloud, both Chromium and Iceweasel works flawlessly with all above 4 versions.

*(edit 2)*
I am pleased to quote ClouldFlare's swift reply to my request for help as follows:

```
This is strange- can you reenable CloudFlare on your trial subdomain and try a few things to see if we can narrow this down:

- Go to the 'Speed' page on the dashboard.
- Disable Rocket Loader by setting it to off
- If this doesn't correct the issue, try toggling the Minify options off at the top of the Speed page.
Rocket loader is a beta feature and so can sometimes cause issues- it is difficult to ensure 100% compatibility with all javascript on the web.
```

*After I disabled Rocket Loader as ClouldFlare's expert told me, all the issues I encountered are gone!* I am happy to mark this question as `answered`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wait for anything to call `Polymer({is:'my-element'});`  What you do do is have an ready function is the object you call Polymer with to tell you when its ready to go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id="my-element">
        <template>
            <paper-input></paper-input>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
     Polymer({
       is: 'my-element',
       ready: function() {
         console.log('element ready')
       }
     });

    </script>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Normally you would declare the `my-element` object in another file that you would import.

Also, if you want to use any databinding at the index.html level you can use the  element, which you then can listen for all elements in it complete, so

```
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <my-element></my-element>
  </template>
  <script>
   var app = document.getElementById('app');
   app.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
    //perform app initialisation here
   });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, you _do_ have to wait for `HTMLImports.whenReady` or `WebComponentsReady` if you are using the HTMLImport Polyfill and calling `Polymer` inside the main document.

Comment: @akc42 Thanks for the enlightenment! Chrome correctly displayed the page *once* today with your integrated (single index.html rather than two files) version. Firefox never did. Please refer to my edits.